# Can a human acquire a memory of an animal?

Tags: human-biology, zoology, brain, memory

I would like to know if it's possible for a human to acquire an animal memory.

I mean, animals store their memories in their brain, right? And so do we, humans, store our memory.

**So, is it possible to cut off an inch (or something like that) of an animal brain,
also to cut off an inch of a human brain, and to replace that animal brain-piece in the missing part of the human's brain?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it can't be done for a lot of reasons. Here are just a few.

1) Memories are stored in electrical pathways, not the the cells themselves. You don't have 1000 memories in a chunk of brain that contains 1000 neurons. If you don't get the entire pathway, you won't get the memory.

2) Once a nerve is cut, it won't *fuse* with another cut nerve. All you'll have is a chunk of dying animal brain in your head. Even if a skilled neurosurgeon united the blood vessels of your brain to those of the chunk to keep it alive, the nerves themselves wouldn't become a working part of your brain. All you'd have (at best) is a useless chunk of another animal's brain sitting where your now-missing chunk was.

3) Animals are different from us. Your body would recognize the different-animal brain matter as foreign, and would make antibodies to it and reduce it to mush (if one didn't die of infection before then).

Comment: @ShadowRealm if this answered your question, please indicate as such by clicking the check mark next to it (it will turn green). Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.

Comment: Do we even comprehend memory that well? Cause from what I know we don't.

Comment: The other answer has been deleted but I think raised an important point specific to the original question : "is it possible to transfer _animal_ memories into a human's mind." This answer answers the more broad question : "is it possible to physically transplant one brain's memory into another person's brain."  If we assume that memories are in no way transferable, then there is no need to distinguish between human-to-human vs animal-to-human. But if we accept a science-fictional possibility (think Dollhouse) for human-to-human, are other animals still too foreign to transfer?

Comment: @Anthony - I'm not aware of how memories were transferred in dollhouse. Can you explain?

Comment: It's pretty silly. "Dolls" undergo a procedure where their brain is "wiped" and special hardware is installed, making their memory "storage" like a blank floppy disk. Meanwhile, a source mind can have their minds mapped to get their mind's "image" mapped and copied into some storable format. This image can then be loaded to the doll's brain. Think of it as "copy as image" and then printed to reformatted disk.

Comment: It's interesting that through the ages, our brains have been compared to the latest technologies. Descartes compared the brain to a hydraulic machine. Freud likened emotions to pressure building up in a steam engine. The brain later resembled a telephone switchboard and then an electrical circuit before evolving into a computer; lately it’s turning into a Web browser or the Internet. But the brain isn't like a computer. If it's wiped, truly wiped of higher functions, we would not be able to reprogram it, or reboot it, or replace it. What was there before would be gone forever.

Comment: Is there a citation for the memory stored in electrical pathways? I didn't know human memory was figured out.

Comment: @vajra78 - just out of curiosity, where/how do you think memories are obtained/kept? Here's one small example. [Intracellular Correlates of Acquisition and Long-Term Memory of Classical Conditioning in Purkinje Cell Dendrites in Slices of Rabbit Cerebellar Lobule HVI](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/18/14/5498.abstract)

Comment: I don't know. But electrical pathways run across the cells. It is clear that networks of neurons store memories. I can't find one nice study done using a new type of optical technique to turn memories on and off in a mouse model. Even so with all the research no one would bet their life on understanding how a memory is stored. There could very well be molecular structures associated with those networks allowing for differentiation. Something must make one network standout from another.

Comment: Also instead of transplanting nerves, what if the signals were routed via a wire. The thing is you would need the references from the animal mind. I'm jumping here but I would wager that a complete memory references memories from the sense and emotional regions in the brain. Very much like a relational database. But I wouldn't bet to much money.

Comment: @vajra78 - I would wager with you.